# ExtJS - How to build development app with PWA?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, build, progressive-web-apps

We have an ExtJS 6.2.1.167 application with PWA support, if we build for production the PWA files like `service-worker.js` are generated, but using `sencha app watch` no PWA files are generated.

We use Sencha Cmd version v7.4.0.39

How can I make it build the application with PWA support when I run `sencha app watch`?

Comment: did you try to modify the development build options. Should be possible. Go to `app.json` and search for "production". Then add "development" wiht similar values.

Comment: @Dinkheller yes I tried that, if you can come with a working example and post as answer I would immediately accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Sencha support and they said it's not possible to have PWA support when using the `sencha app watch` command.